# EF TPT Indexes on derived tables

Tags: entity-framework-6

When we use TPT inheritance in Entity Framework, it creates 2 indexes on the pk field of the derived table.
One PK - Clustered Index
Second - A non-clustered Index.

Is it done with a purpose OR an error.
If it is a purpose, whats the purpose?
If it is an error, how can I correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a side-effect of the derived PK to be also the FK. Entity Framework automatically indexes FK columns.

It's not a bug. It's just not being overly smart. I think.

I believe you can drop the second index as it's giving you anything in terms of performance.